# Exposed wiring solution?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Looking for some advice.  I want to add a chandelier to our family room but I do not have the ability to run the electrical behind the wood ceiling.  Is there a way to run the power exposed without using metal conduit?  Is there a plastic solution or something else that I could easily paint for it to blend in?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A "swag" or hanging cord suspended from hooks is one approach to this problem. Special cordage that is "dressier" than standard cord is available to make it look better, but it's either a look you hate or one you can live with (perhaps, for a few, it's a look you love?) Seems like it's been out of fashion a long time, but was more popular once.

Answer (score 2):

Wiremold V500 or V700 is typically used for this.  It has a nice finished appearance if it's installed correctly.  It doesn't take any special tools to work with, it cut easily with a hacksaw.  You do have to do a good job with your layout to make it look good.

[image: Wiremold V500]